# Mostrar las carpetas del directorio

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".DOCcontenido_t").click(function(){
        $(this).find("DOCcontenido_t_p").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
<?php
$directorio = opendir("."); //ruta actual
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
    //verificamos si es o no un directorio
    if (is_dir($archivo)){
        //si es el directorio . o .. no lo mostramos
        if($archivo!="." AND $archivo!=".."){
            //de ser un directorio lo mostramos
            echo "<p class='DOCcontenido_t'>".$archivo;
            //obtener el contenido del directorio
            $contenido=opendir("./".$archivo);
            while($archivocontent = readdir($contenido)){
                //Verificamos que no sea ni el directorio . ni el ..
                if($archivocontent!="." AND $archivocontent!=".."){
                    //Verificamos si es un directorio
                    if(is_dir($archivocontent)){
                        //Mostramos el contenido
                        echo "<p class='DOCcontenido_t_p'>".$archivocontent."</p>";
                    }
                }
            }
            echo "</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Lo que quiero hacer:**

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar las carpetas de la carpeta actual y las subcarpetas de dicha carpeta.

Un ejemplo:

-Carpeta 1
| +Subcarpeta 1
| +Subcarpeta 2
| +Subcarpeta 3
-Carpeta 2
...

**Mi problema**

```
                    if(is_dir($archivocontent)){
                        //Mostramos el contenido
                        echo "<p class='DOCcontenido_t_p'>".$archivocontent."</p>";
                    }
```

Cuando compruebo que si las subcarpetas son carpetas no ejecuta el echo. Y si quito ese if muestra todo el contenido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solucione mi propio problema. Por si a alguien le sirve:

Busca en el directorio actual los ficheros `.php` de dentro de las carpetas hijo de los padres.

```
$directorio = opendir("."); //ruta actual
//Este while es para las categorias
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
    //verificamos si es o no un directorio
    if (is_dir($archivo)){
        //si es el directorio . o .. no lo mostramos
        if($archivo!="." AND $archivo!=".."){
            $check_if_have_content=false;
            //obtener el contenido del directorio
            $contenido=opendir("./".$archivo);
            while($archivocontent = readdir($contenido)){
                //Verificamos que no sea ni el directorio . ni el ..
                if($archivocontent!="." AND $archivocontent!=".."){
                    //Verificamos si es un directorio
                    if(is_dir($archivo."/".$archivocontent)){
                        //Si es un directorio y contiene directorios. Se mostrará
                        $contenido_2=opendir("./".$archivo."/".$archivocontent);
                        if(isset($contenido_2)){
                            while($archivocontent_2=readdir($contenido_2)){
                                //Verificamos si tiene algo dentro del fichero, que no sea una carpeta y que sea un .php
                                if($archivocontent_2!="." AND $archivocontent_2!=".."){
                                    if(!is_dir($archivo."/".$archivocontent."/".$archivocontent_2)){
                                        if(pathinfo($archivocontent_2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=="php"){
                                            $check_if_have_content=true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if($check_if_have_content==true){
                echo "<p class='DOCcontenido_t'>".$archivo."</p>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```